Как работает map в python?
Задача:
На вход программе подается строка с числами новых подписчиков канала по дням, записанных в одну строку через пробел. Необходимо прочитать эти числа и сохранить в списке, как целые числа в порядке их следования в строке. Затем, вывести через пробел на экран максимальное, минимальное и суммарное значения этого списка.
Правильное решение:
i = map(int, input().split())
I = list(i)
print(max(I), min(I), sum(I))

Мое решение:
i = str(input().split())
print(max(i), min(i), sum(i))

Объясните, пожалуйста, на указанном выше примере, как работает функция map?
Моя логика такова, что нам по заданию нужно получить список, который можно получить, применив в строке метод .split. Почему это не работает? Какая логика этому противоречит?
И особенно мне не понятно, каким образом мы применяем .split к int, если это метод строки, а int - число

ну это оно после map становится числом, а сплит применяется раньше, когда оно еще строка. а в вашем примере ничего не делает строку числом

В вашем решении элементы сравниваются как строки - алфавитно. Так получится, что "10" меньше "2" (точно так же как "ab" раньше чем "b" по алфавиту). map применяет указанную функцию (int) к каждому элементу входного списка, после этого уже сравнение нормально выполняется. Каким образом применяет - условно, map внутри идет циклом по списку, из первого аргумента берет функцию, ее вызывает, передавая внутрь элемент.

"Правильное решение" тоже не сахар, непонятно, зачем нужна промежуточная переменная, почему сразу list не применён после map, без переменной, ну и называть переменные одной буквой, но в разном регистре... И вообще в питоне большие буквы - для классов, а для переменных - только маленькие буквы. Так проще не запутаться где что.

Согласно документации функция работает следующим образом:
map(function, iterable, *iterables), где аргумент function - функция которая будет применяться к каждому элементу iterable.
То есть в вашем случае, рольfunction выполняет int, роль iterable у input().split(). Значения введенные в input является строкой. split() разделяет эту строку по пробелам и возвращает список из строчных объектов. И далее к каждому элементу этого списка применяется int, который возвращает целое число.
map(int, input().split()) для понимания можно расписать как:
str_list = input().split()

int_list = []
for i in str_list:
    int_list.append(int(i))

print(f'{int_list=}')

Только map() возвращает объект класса map, поэтому необходимо применять list, что бы конвертировать в список.
Ссылка на документацию по map:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Супер, понял, большое спасибо
Не совсем только понимаю, зачем ответ выводить в виде f-строки?
Не первый раз это вижу, но в прошлый раз не задался вопросом.
Почему нельзя просто вывести 3 переменные через запятую?

@HanZo для пущей наглядности. print(f'{int_list=}') выведет int_list=[данные списка], а просто print(int_list) выведет сразу список [данные списка]. Если много переменных их можно так же выводить через запятую по аналогии, либо без f, либо с f

Код разбит на элементарные подвыражения, в том порядке в каком они вычисляются. Комментарии над блоком - строки исходного кода. Комментарии справа - промежуточные результаты вычислений:
# i = map(int, input().split())
_1 = int
_2 = input()                   # '1 2 3'
_3 = _2.split                  # <built-in method split of str object at 0x7f7f0fc725b0>
_4 = _3()                      # ['1', '2', '3']
i = map(_1, _4)                # <map object at 0x7f7f0fc2a9b0>


# I = list(i)
_5 = i                         # <map object at 0x7f7f0fc2a9b0>
I = list(_5)                   # [1, 2, 3]


# print(max(I), min(I), sum(I))
_6 = I                         # [1, 2, 3]
_7 = max(_6)                   # 3
_8 = min(_6)                   # 1
_9 = sum(_6)                   # 6
print(_7, _8, _9)              # None

P.S. Для краткости не все подвыражения раскрыты полностью. Например, вызов функции тоже раскрывается компилятором:
# _9 = sum(_6)
_10 = sum                      # <built-in function sum>
_9 = _10(_6)                   # 6


Большое спасибо!
